# Unsupported operation when trying to remotely create new MySQL user via HashiCorp Vault

Tags: mysql, hashicorp-vault

I have deployed HashiCorp Vault in a Linux VM, and I want it to connect to an instance of MySQL database running on my host machine.

In my database (host machine IP 100.101.102.103), I have created a user especially for this purpose:

```
CREATE USER 'vaultuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'vaultpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON amdb.* TO 'vaultuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* to 'vaultuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In my Vault (VM IP 200.201.202.203), I have run the following steps:

0. Start Vault - `vault server -dev -dev-listen-address="0.0.0.0:8200"`. I see that my root token is `hvs.ROOTTOKEN`
1. Enable the database secrets engine - `vault secrets enable database`
2. Configure Vault with the proper plugin and connection information - `vault write database/config/mydb plugin_name=mysql-database-plugin connection_url="{{username}}:{{password}}@tcp(100.101.102.103:3306)/mydb" allowed_roles="vault-role" username="vaultuser" password="vaultpass"`
3. Force root password rotation - `vault write -force database/rotate-root/mydb`. At this point, I can no longer login to my database with `mysql -uvaultuser -pvaultpass`
4. Configure a role that maps a name in Vault to a set of creation statements to create the database credential - `vault write database/roles/vault-role db_name=mydb creation_statements="CREATE USER '{{name}}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{{password}}';GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO '{{name}}'@'%';" default_ttl="1h" max_ttl="24h"`

Now, I want to create a new user remotely. On a separate machine (let's say 192.168.100.200), I run `curl -X POST -H "X-Vault-Token: hvs.ROOTTOKEN" http://200.201.202.203:8200/v1/database/creds/vault-role`. The response I see is

```
{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* unsupported operation\n\n"]}
```

I am not sure what I have done wrongly. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with software development, this is pure database admin / IT security type of problem. Please use the dedicated sister sites of SO for asking such questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably has nothing to do with your configuration. The operation Vault is complaining about is the `POST` because the [generate credentials endpoint is a `GET` operation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/databases#generate-credentials).

Remove `-X POST` from your curl request.